# Possibility of omitting 'the' before an already mentioned object

Tags: definite-article

In the second clause of the following sentence, would it be necessary to put 'the' before 'vegetables'?

> In the store, he bought fruits and cookies but not vegetables,
> because his kids don't like vegetables.

Although 'vegetables' is used once in the first clause, it does not specify any objects. Then, I wonder if 'the' is needed in the following clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't needed. It would still make sense with 'the' but it doesn't sound so natural.

Answer (score 0):

It would be *wrong* to use a definite article in the second clause. The first one mentioned an *absence* of vegetables, not any particular ones.